# @google/clasp upgrade throwing syntax error; code base is in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, clasp

- We have a google calendar add-on written in TypeScript.
- We are using the local ide for the development as suggested by google doc.
- We are using @google/clasp to convert from TypeScript to AppScript and upload it on google drive.

Now, when we are trying to upload our code through the clasp, it’s throwing too many syntax error for the same code base that was currently working fine. It started happening when we have upgraded the clasp version@2.3.0.

a.  Clasp version@ 2.3.0 => failed to convert and upload code to google drive(Same code that is currently running into prod)

b.  Clasp version@1.6.0 => Still working fine

Error :

```js
[
    {
      message: 'Syntax error: Missing ; before statement. line: 9175 file: code-3.12.0',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'badRequest'
    }
  ]
```

What will be causing this error ?

Comment: Can you share the command you are running?

Comment: We use **clasp push**.

Comment: I found this on the clasp repo: https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/722#issuecomment-570146616 perhaps it helps you.

Comment: There have been a lot of changes between the two versions, you could try going through the changes https://github.com/google/clasp/compare/1.6.0...2.2.0 or upgrade incrementally to find where the syntax errors are coming from. Also first uninstall clasp, npm update and reinstall with newer version